# Single miniature part with zener diodes in series

Tags: diodes

[image]

([source](https://www.onsemi.cn/pub/Collateral/HBD854-D.PDF))

Is there any single part/assembly with zener diodes in SOT-23 package (or comparable with 3 pins)?

I can use BAT54S for diodes, but can not find similar for zeners. The goal is a minimal footprint, limiting audio signal to ±5 V.

Comment: filtering zeners to `dual anti parallel` at a supplier site returns MMBZ5237BS-7-F  ... the package was larger than SOT-23, but it may give you a starting point

Comment: Comment only: His diodes are effectively in series unless individually isolated (which your cited ones are).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are integrated port protection networks that may do what you want in one or two packages.

You'll have to evaluate the breakdown voltages and tolerances to see if they meet all your (unstated) requirements. Generally the "zener" is a TVS which is like a Zener diode, but beefier.

Eg. (from a Wurth datasheet): (there are many others, and some variations in topology).

[image]